# How to ease the whole css animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

As you can see from this snippet, the easing from "vuelo" interpolates and eases stoping at every position marked by the keyframes: 10, 20, 30, 40...

Instead, I'd like the easing to interpolate along the whole animation, is it possible?

```css
body {
  background: #999;
}
.espacio {
  background: white;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  perspective: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*prevents scroll in some browsers */
}
.mariposa {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  /*border: 1px #CCC solid;*/
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(40deg);
  -webkit-animation: vuelo 20s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: vuelo 20s ease-in-out infinite;
}
.alaL {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #5795C2;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  transform: rotateY(30deg);
  -webkit-animation: batir 1s ease infinite;
  animation: batir 1s ease infinite;
}
.alaR {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  background: #5795C2;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  transform: rotateY(-30deg);
  -webkit-animation: batir 1s linear infinite;
  animation: batir 1s linear infinite;
}
.circulo {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background: purple;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: -12px 0 0 -12px;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
}
@-webkit-keyframes batir {
  50% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg)
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes vuelo {
  10% {
    transform: translate(100px, 30px) rotate3d(1, -0.5, 0, 60deg)
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(200px, 100px) rotate3d(1, -1, 0, 90deg)
  }
  30% {
    transform: translate(250px, 150px) rotate3d(0.8, -1, 0, 100deg)
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(200px, 100px) rotate3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 60deg)
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate(400px, 200px) rotate3d(0.8, -0.5, 0, 90deg)
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(100px, 300px) rotate3d(1, -1, 0, 90deg)
  }
}
@keyframes batir {
  50% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg)
  }
}
@keyframes vuelo {
  10% {
    transform: translate(100px, 30px) rotate3d(1, -0.5, 0, 60deg)
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(200px, 100px) rotate3d(1, -1, 0, 90deg)
  }
  30% {
    transform: translate(250px, 150px) rotate3d(0.8, -1, 0, 100deg)
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(200px, 100px) rotate3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 60deg)
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate(400px, 200px) rotate3d(0.8, -0.5, 0, 90deg)
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(100px, 300px) rotate3d(1, -1, 0, 90deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="espacio">
  <div class="mariposa">
    <div class="alaL">
      <div class="circulo"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="alaR">
      <div class="circulo"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`animation-timing-function`s are interpolated between keyframes, so the only way to make them span over the whole cycle is to have no intermediate keyframes.

As a workaround, you could try to approximate the intended behaviour by using a different timing function, like `linear`, and shift keyframe "positions" (on the timeline).

For example *(I removed the `-webkit-` parts to make it more readable)*:

```css
body {
  background: #999;
}
.espacio {
  background: white;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  perspective: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*prevents scroll in some browsers */
}
.mariposa {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  /*border: 1px #CCC solid;*/
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(40deg);
  animation: vuelo 10s linear infinite;
}
.alaL {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #5795C2;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  transform: rotateY(30deg);
  animation: batir 1s ease infinite;
}
.alaR {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  background: #5795C2;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  transform: rotateY(-30deg);
  animation: batir 1s linear infinite;
}
.circulo {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background: purple;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: -12px 0 0 -12px;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
}
@keyframes batir {
  50% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg)
  }
}
@keyframes vuelo {
  5% {
    transform: translate(100px, 30px) rotate3d(1, -0.5, 0, 60deg)
  }
  15% {
    transform: translate(200px, 100px) rotate3d(1, -1, 0, 90deg)
  }
  30% {
    transform: translate(250px, 150px) rotate3d(0.8, -1, 0, 100deg)
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(200px, 100px) rotate3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 60deg)
  }
  70% {
    transform: translate(400px, 200px) rotate3d(0.8, -0.5, 0, 90deg)
  }
  90% {
    transform: translate(100px, 300px) rotate3d(1, -1, 0, 90deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="espacio">
  <div class="mariposa">
    <div class="alaL">
      <div class="circulo"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="alaR">
      <div class="circulo"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Just be aware that abrupt direction changes like you have in your animation may look weird. To soften them, you could animate `translateX` and `translateY` independently.